# How to analyze C++ code performance using Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c++, performance, cpu-usage

I have a big project in ANSI C++ that was originally written in C# and CLI C++, and was translated to ANSI C++. The performance of the ANSI C++ project is much slower on the same input then then of the original project.

I am using VS2015. How can i analyze the ANSI C++ project to find out the CPU usage of every function, so i can find the culprits that slow down the execution?

Comment: Have you looks at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx)?

Comment: Yes thanks. I was hoping to get some pro tips for handling this situation. It's the first time i try to analyze the performance of a big project and hope to get some more advice from performance experts

Comment: The pro tip is to profile. Also make sure you are running the release build. A debug build can be 100 times slower than release.

Comment: @darkThoughts what you are asking is awfully vague. You should go through the process as described by Microsoft, and come back to SE with specific questions if you get stuck.